# How to do this in javascript (array_multisort php)

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I would like to know how I do this in javascript.

**array_multisort($array1, SORT_DESC, $array2);**

This is my example of php code but I would like to know how it is done in javascript

```
    $array1 = array(
    '11' => 1,
    '12' => 2,
    '14' => 4,
    '19' => 5,
    '19' => 5,
    '19' => 5
    );



    $array2 = array('11' => ['test'],
                    '12' => ['test'],
                    '14' => ['test'],
                    '19' => ['test 19'],
                    '19' => ['test 19'],
                    '19' => ['test 19']);



    array_multisort($array1, SORT_DESC, $array2);
```

> //result

```
print_r($array2);

   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => test 19
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => test
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => test
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => test
            )

    )
```

Comment: I'd `zip` them together, `sort` using a callback comparing the value you care about, then `unzip` them back into separate arrays.

Comment: What did you try?